# Python - How to get backgroundColor from QListWidgetItem

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

i want to get item from QList Widget and added it into QListWidgetItem var and everything is fine, but after that i need background color of this item and :

```
    item = self.Listbox.takeItem(i)
    print(item.backgroundColor)
```

For this i have got error that backgroundColor **attribute does not exist**

At PyQt4 the attribute exist:

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidgetitem.html#backgroundColor

But what can i use on PyQt5?

-

The output of print(dir(item)) :

[image]

Comment: what's the result of print(dir(item))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is

```
item.background().color().getRgb()
```

To get the RGB value e.g. (0, 0, 0, 255)

Longer answer is that backgroundColor() is now obsolete see http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidgetitem-obsolete.html

> (obsolete) QColor     backgroundColor() const

So you have to get the QBrush  using background() and then get QColor using color()  then get RGB or what ever you want see http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcolor.html

Comment: Yep it seems to be fine :) but how can i compare that colors now? something like `if Item.background().color().getRgb() == QColor(255,0,0,255):`

Comment: You could use item.background().color().value() which is numeric

Comment: I can´t for example clear blue and clear red has both 255 numeric from .value() method

Comment: As you saying green and red are different but red and blue has both 255 :-O

Comment: Red gives 255 green gives 128 if you use value()

Comment: You are right but try Blue and Red i have got 255 for both

Comment: I'm guessing it is a problem with the translation to the underlying library the documentation says lowercase red but Red seems to function as expected but cant be read via value() if you stick to lowercase it should work as expected pity there is little documentation about these values or use RGB

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it answers your question or comment again if you need further assistance

Comment: @Dan-Dev. The `value()` is the V component in the HSV color model (Hue|Saturation|Value). Two different colours can have the same `value()`, just as they can have the same `blue()` in the RGB colour model. It's the combination of *all three components* that differentiates them. If you want to compare colours, just do it directly: `item.background().color() == QColor(255, 0, 0)`. You can also use `color.name()` to get a string representation (e.g. `#ff0000`).

Comment: I stand corrected and have removed the updated part from the answer. My original answer still stands using getRgb().

Answer (score 0):

```
#Get backgroundColor from QListWidgetItem
#This is the example code for Get backgroundColor from QListWidgetItem
#If your are not expecting this answer, sorry.
#Thanks, Subin Gopi

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 200, 150))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName ('listWidget')        
        self.resize(250, 200)

        self.listWidget.itemPressed.connect (self.getColor)        
        self.addItems ()


    def addItems (self) :
        itemList        = {'Apple':'red', 'Orange':'#ff5500', 'Grape':'blue', 'Bean':'green', 'Banana':'yellow'}
        for eachItem in itemList :
            currentItem = QtGui.QListWidgetItem (self.listWidget)           

            #Set Color
            bgBrush     = QtGui.QBrush()
            bgBrush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)

            #Qt.GlobalColor
            bgBrush.setColor (QtGui.QColor(itemList[eachItem]))            
            #RGB Value 
            #bgBrush.setColor (QtGui.QColor(170, 85, 255))            
            currentItem.setBackground(bgBrush)

            fgBrush     = QtGui.QBrush()
            fgBrush.setColor (QtGui.QColor('black'))            
            currentItem.setForeground (fgBrush)

            #Set text
            currentItem.setText(eachItem)

    def getColor (self) :
        currentItem     = self.listWidget.selectedItems ()
        currentBrush    = currentItem[-1].background ()
        rgbColor        = currentBrush.color ().red (), currentBrush.color ().green (), currentBrush.color ().blue ()
        strColor        = currentBrush.color ().name ()

        print ('rgb- Color\t', rgbColor)
        print ('str- Color\t', strColor, '\n')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```